# Docker + PNPM + NX issue

Tags: node.js, docker, monorepo, pnpm, nomachine-nx

I have a troubleshoot with Docker and a monorepo based on PNPM Workspace + NX.

It simply doesn't compile.

I get the message :

```
=> ERROR [ 9/12] RUN pnpm build-schema                                                                              1.0s
------
 > [ 9/12] RUN pnpm build-schema:
#0 0.495
#0 0.495 > profilart@1.0.0 build-schema /
#0 0.495 > npx nx build schemas
#0 0.495
#0 0.937
#0 0.938  >  NX   The current directory isn't part of an Nx workspace.
#0 0.938
#0 0.938    To create a workspace run:
#0 0.938    npx create-nx-workspace@latest <workspace name>
#0 0.938
#0 0.938    To add Nx to existing workspace run with a workspace-specific nx.json:
#0 0.938    npx add-nx-to-monorepo@latest
#0 0.938
#0 0.938    To add the default nx.json file run:
#0 0.938    nx init
#0 0.938
#0 0.938
#0 0.942  >  NX   For more information please visit https://nx.dev/
#0 0.942
#0 0.961  ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
```

What I don't understand is that it is already on an Nx workspace as I used the command `pnpm add nx -D -w`

My pnpm-workspace.yaml contains this :

```
# pnpm-workspace.yaml
packages:
  # executable/launchable applications
  - 'apps/*'
  # all packages in subdirs of packages/ and components/
  - 'packages/*'
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npx nx run-many --target=start --all ",
    "dev": "npx nx run-many --target=dev --all",
    "start-bo": "npx nx start xxx-bo ",
    "start-bo:dev": "npx nx dev xxx-bo ",
    "start-api": "npx nx start xxx-api",
    "start-api:dev": "npx nx start:dev xxx-api",
    "build": "npx nx run-many --target=build --all",
    "build-bo": "npx nx build xxx-bo",
    "build-api": "npx nx build xxx-api",
    "build-schema": "npx nx build schemas"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "nx": "^15.2.4",
    "concurrently": "^7.6.0"
  }
}
```

start-bo and start-api refer to projects based in /apps folder which have their own package.json. API is based on NESTJS and BO on React + NextJS.

My dockerfile has this :

```
# Filename: Dockerfile

FROM node:alpine

ENV NODE_VERSION 16.17.0

RUN npm install -g pnpm
RUN npm install typescript -g

RUN apk add make gcc g++

RUN apk add --update --no-cache python3 && ln -sf python3 /usr/bin/python
ADD / /
WORKDIR /

COPY . .

RUN pnpm install --prod

RUN pnpm build-schema
RUN pnpm build-api 
RUN pnpm build-bo

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["pnpm" "start"]
```

It fails when I launch `RUN pnpm build-schema`.

I actually use the root folder since it doesn't work in sub folders because of gcc used to compile scrypt (it's another problem I'll treat later).

Is there something I missed?

I try to run `npx add-nx-to-monorepo@latest` and it just doesn't move, I forced stopping after 5 minutes, it's blocked.

Thanks for your help.